# How to change the width of an NSView in a transparent window

Tags: swift, macos

(Swift, macOS, storyboard)

I have an NSView in a transparent window

I have this in the viewDidLoad. To make the window transparent and the NSView blue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2){
    self.view.window?.isOpaque = false
    self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
}
view1.wantsLayer = true
view1.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
```

[image]

I want to change the width with code when I click a button.
If it has constraints:

```
@IBAction func button1(_ sender: NSButton) {
    view1Width.constant = 74
}
```

I tried without constraints and different ways to change the width. They all give the same results:

```
view1.frame = NSRect(x:50, y:120, width:74, height:100)
```

[image]

But there is still a border and a shadow where the old shape was. Why does it happen and how to solve it?

It only happens in specific circumstances:

- If the window is transparent (and macOS)
- I change the width and do not change the position y
- The window must be active. If it is not (If I click to anywhere else) it looks as it should: the shadow around the changed NSView green.

(I have simplified the case to try to find a solution. I have created a new document and there is only this code and I am sure there is no other element)

Comment: Are there any missing constraints, if yes then fix it and check if it works now?

Comment: I tried but it makes no difference. Thank you for trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the window is transparent you need to invalidate the shadows.

Apple states about invalidateShadow()

> Invalidates the window shadow so that it is recomputed based on the current window shape.

**Complete Self-Contained Test Program**

It sets up the UI pogrammatically instead of using a storyboard. Other than that, the code is very close to your example.

Note the line:

```
view.window?.invalidateShadow()
```

in the onChange method.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private let view1 = NSView()
    private let changeButton = NSButton()
    private var view1Width: NSLayoutConstraint?
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2){
            self.view.window?.isOpaque = false
            self.view.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        }
        view1.wantsLayer = true
        view1.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    }
    
    @objc private func onChange() {
        view1Width?.constant += 32
        view.window?.invalidateShadow()
    }
    
    private func setupUI() {
        changeButton.title = "change"
        changeButton.bezelStyle = .rounded
        changeButton.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)
        changeButton.target = self
        changeButton.action = #selector(onChange)
        
        self.view.addSubview(view1)
        self.view.addSubview(changeButton)
        
        self.view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.changeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            view1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            view1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128),
            
            changeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.bottomAnchor, constant:16),
            changeButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.centerXAnchor)
        ])
        
        view1Width = view1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128)
        view1Width?.isActive = true
    }

}
```

**Result**

The desired result with an update of the shadows is accomplished:
[image: shadow demo]

Comment: To sum up for other people: we have to add view.window?.invalidateShadow() and make the object in code. If I make the objects in the storyboard that line makes no difference. Is that a bug?

Comment: Yes, invalidateShadow() is needed to inform the system about the _change_ of the shape of the window. However, you don't need to create the UI in code. I created the UI in code because it's easier to share - also, my preferred method for UI creation. But the same can be achieved with a storyboard.  Just create the same UI with the same constraints in the storyboard. I also tested it briefly. Have then zipped the project, it can be downloaded from: https://www.software7.biz/so/iertzzaoeslkdjfoealskjdf/WidthChangeOfView.zip

Comment: You are right. The question is not if it is made in code or storyboard. It is if I use animator() or not.
This works well with invalidateShadow: View2WidthConstraint.constant = 74

This does not work: View2WidthConstraint.constant = 74
(It works if I click the button later when the animation has finished)